# A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share. what does it means?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework

I Build an ASP.NET project with PL,BL,DAl, BE of Entity Data Model(=.edmx) which I generated from a service Based DB (= .mdf) which is located in my DAL project.

I did copied the connectionString from the BE app.config to the PL web.config

**what's wrong? why I get this error:**

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An attempt to attach an auto-named
>   database for file C:\Documents and Settings\user\שולחן העבודה\למידה
>   אישית\Lev\Lev\App_Data\Midrasha.mdf failed. A database with the same
>   name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on
>   UNC share.

my code logic is PL->BL->DAL- > try to save the new object to the DB.
the code line which generate the problem is :

```
public void AddFeedback(Feedback feed)
{
    MidrashaEntities _context = new MidrashaEntities();
    _context.Feedback.AddObject(feed);
    _context.SaveChanges();  <-------throw the exception
}
```

`Feedback` is a table in my DAL's SQL which I generate as Object entity.

Comment: UNC is the naming format with `\\server\share\path\file.ext`. As opposed to plain old DOS/Windows `D:\path\file.ext`. Accessing UNC shares from a server-based app (like an ASP.NET one) is tricky.

Comment: no, I'm not on a network. my project is located on the desktop

Comment: I'd say that the 'שולחן העבודה\למידה אישית' characters are making the mess. Are you able to move the mdf file somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error before My Error before in the Connection String so make sure you have the right Connection String

Answer (score 0):

If your on a network and your doc's folder is a share to the AD this will screw you up.  Try to move your project to:

```
C:\MYProject\
```

and see if that fixes it.